# Binary to Decimal in Java Script

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal

So I'm trying to convert binary to decimal in Javascript:

```
    function binToDec(){
        var binary = document.getElementById("binaryInput").value.split("").reverse();
        var toDecimal = function(binary) {

            return parseInt(binary,2);
        }
   }
```

But it's not working out for me... I'm new to JS so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Also, here is the "binaryInput" reference:

```
    <td colspan="2"><input id="binaryInput" type="text" name="First Number" onfocus='onFocusInput(this);'></td>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Liam I looked at that one and tried out the code, but it didn't work out for me...

Comment: 1) why are you splitting the value
2) why are you reversing the input
3) `function binToDec(){return parseInt(document.getElementById("binaryInput").value,2);}` should do the trick, obviously I'm not checking for correctness of the input here, for that you could add a RegExp /[01]+/g or something alike.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are `split`ting the input string. Look at the [`parseInt` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If string [the value] is not a string, then it is converted to one.

However, converting the array (which is created because you `split` the string) back to a string results in `'1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0'`, not `'10101000'`. `'1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0'` is not a valid binary number and `parseInt` therefore fails.

If you really want to reverse the input, you should use

```
document.getElementById("binaryInput").value.split("").reverse().join("");
```

which generates the correct string. If you don't want to reverse it, use

```
document.getElementById("binaryInput").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this:

```
function binToDec(){
  //get the string from the input element
  var binString = document.getElementById("binaryInput").value;

  //remove any non binary character
  binString = binString.replace(/[^01]+/g,'');

  if(binString>''){
    //if you want it to be reversed: binString = binString.split('').reverse().join('')
    return parseInt(binString,2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```